# Unity AWS S3 Asset Bundle Downloading

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3

**Is there an effective way to utilized Unity's built in Caching system with the AWS SDKfor Unity?**

My current solution below creates an asset-bundle from a memory stream, and requires my own simple caching system. I've checked my local cache and it doesn't appear that the AWS sdk utilizes `LoadFromCacheOrDownload`, or does any caching of it's own. ( Determined by going in to my local cache and not finding any S3 objects)

This works fine for me as is. A caching solution is pretty simple. I'm just concerned I'm not using the plugin as effectively as possible.

**Sidebar**: Is using a memory stream even an efficient way to make asset bundles from S3 GetObjectAsync?

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Get Object from S3 Bucket
    /// </summary>
    public void GetAssetBundle(string BucketName, string AssetBundlePath, Action<AssetBundle> AssetBundleCallback)
    {
        s3Client.GetObjectAsync(BucketName, AssetBundlePath, (responseObj) =>
        {
            if (responseObj.Response == null)
            {
                AssetBundleCallback(null);
                return;
            }
            byte[] data = null;
            var response = responseObj.Response;
            if (response.ResponseStream != null)
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.ResponseStream))
                {
                    using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        var buffer = new byte[512];
                        var bytesRead = default(int);
                        while ((bytesRead = reader.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            memstream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        data = memstream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            var bundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromMemory(data);
            bundle.name = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            if (bundle == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Bundle empty");
                AssetBundleCallback(null);
            }
            else
            {
                AssetBundleCallback(bundle);
            }

        });
    }
```